# deserialize stringBuffer

Tags: java, hibernate, deserialization, stringbuffer

I have a db varchar field looks like the result of Java StringBuffer serialization:

```
íjava.lang.StringBuffer [many random characters here removed for this question]
```

how do I deserialize it into String?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Could you post the class that you are mapping, and any relevant Hibernate XML? And explain what you mean by "I converted the java class field to String and I want to do a database conversion"?

Comment: Please revert that edit Vanchinathan -- you have broken the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to do this:

```
byte[] varcharContents = ... // get the bytes of the field, not via a String
ObjectInputStream ois = 
    new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(varcharContents));
StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer)ois.readObject();
String s = sb.toString();
```

You'll have to hope that you can really get the original bytes produced by the serialisation back, and that they haven't been transformed on their way to and from the DB.